# Macro Stopping Once a Workbook is Opened

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro that opens 2 workbooks and does some manipulation in one and copies it over to another and then it saves it as a .csv file. The first workbook is opened by defined string variables using the workbooks.open function and the other workbook is opened by the filepath and the filename being values set by the cell values in the worksheet. The goal is to go down the column where the names are stored and open those workbooks, do the manipulation, save as a .csv file, close and then go to the next name in the column list.

```
dim fpath, fname, path, wname, tempname, fpath2 as string
dim mainwkbk, trgwkbk, srcwkbk as workbook
dim  main_ws as worksheet
dim main_lr, name_col as integer
dim q as long

set mainwkbk = workbooks("title1.xlsx")
set main_ws = mainwkbk.worksheets(1)

main_ws.activate
main_lr = main_ws.cells(rows.count,10).end(xlup).row
fpath = Range("I2")

for q = 2 to main_lr
    tempname = "_template_name.csv")
    fpath2 = "C:\temp\locaiton\"
    workbooks.open(fpath2 & tempname)
    set trgwkbk = workbooks(tempname)

    fname = main_ws.cells(q,10).value
    path = fpath & fname & ".xlsx"
    workbooks.open(path)
    set srcwkbk = workbooks(fname & ".xlsx")

    2nd_macro (fname)

next q
```

The 2nd macro does the manipulation, which essentially copes over columns from the .xlsx file to the .csv file and it also runs a 3rd macro. The 2nd and 3rd macros work essentially, because they've been tested independent of the master macro. The macro stops after it opens the 1st workbook. I've looked at other macros I"ve written and I don't recall them stopping after running. I don't have those files anymore so I can't test those macros.

Comment: Some side notes: `workbooks.open(fpath2 & tempname)`, `set trgwkbk = workbooks(tempname)` should be simplified to just `Set trgwkbk = workbooks.open(fpath2 & tempname)`. Same for `workbooks.open(path)` and `set srcwkbk = workbooks(fname & ".xlsx")`.

Comment: Where exactly does it "stop"?  No error messages or other odd behavior?

Comment: @TimWilliams, it stops after the workbooks.open line. When you step through it, immediately after the workbooks.open line run, when F8 is pressed it goes to the top of the macro. no error message when I stop through it. It will go through line once i reach that point again.

Comment: I've never seen that happen - it's just a csv file so it can't have any auto-run VBA in it...

Comment: @TimWilliams it's not just the .csv file where it stops. It also stops with the source file, which is a .xlsx file. Which is why I'm confused because I know the macros where the method to open the files was the same worked fine.

Comment: @TimWilliams i redid the code, but now I'm having trouble saving my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I started from scratch and this is the code I used. it's no different than the first comment.

```
dpath = Range("I2")
fname = Range("J2")
set srcwkbk = workbooks.open(dpath & fname)

tempname = "name.csv"
fpath = "C:\path\"
set trgwkbk = workbooks.open(fpath & tempname)

srcwkbk.activate
call ind_level_calc
transfer_macro (fname)
```

Comment: What is fpath2 ?

Comment: disregard. i found the error. it's variable name for a separate file path, but i missed a 's' in the file path name